# How to pull "publisher" data from BGG - Importxml - google sheets

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I am attempting to pull the publisher information from a list of games, however I'm getting hung up on the pull.

The tutorials or examples I've seen of importXML all deal with relatively simple pulls that don't seem like they are buried in XML code on the webpage and when I try to follow them or adapt them to my situation I get either #NA error parsing or the no content error.

for example I'm trying to pull from URL;
https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/168435/between-two-cities
and I specifically need the publishers listed on that page

My attempt at importing includes this;

```
=IMPORTXML(D2, "//span[4][ng-repeat=]/a/@title=")
```

and a whole slew of other variations on that xquery.

Any guidance or distinctions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it,

Had to use https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/ as the source URL.

Specifically for the URL I posted the answer was;
https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/168435

Syntax for importxml is;
=IMPORTXML(A18, "//boardgames/boardgame/boardgamepublisher") with the A18 being the above URL